# MediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript

Alguem possui algum exemplo para gravação de audio usando o `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`

Comment: Já leu a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) na MDN? Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Estou com dificuldades na captura de áudio... consigo acessar o microfone mas não realizar uma gravação